# Linux Gallium OS

Tags: linux

[image: this is a picture of what my space on my chromebook is.]  Before I installed linux, i had about 12-10 gigabytes available. When i installed linux and gave it 8 gigabytes of data. it was all fine and dandy. until i one day left my chromebook out. Someone else must've used it, because when i turned it on it was completely factory reset. i had to sign myself back in and update stuff. Then i got a notification saying i had 345 megabytes of data left on my chromebook! I went to storage, and i only have 1 gigabyte of data that is usable. I think whoever used my chromebook uninstalled it wrong, is there any way to fix it? It was Dual Boot Linux btw. I  am looking to get my other 9 gigabytes back.

Comment: If someone else used it and made modifications to the system without your knowledge or permission, then I would personally not trust a single byte of what's on that hard drive. I would reinstall the system(s) from scratch and restore personal files from a recent backup.

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: Where would i get the system(s) to re-install chrome OS? and Even if i did that, There is still the partition of a non-existant Linux. I can't switch over to it anymore, so i assume it was deleted when the chromebook was factory reset. But how would i get rid of that partition to access the other gigabytes?

Comment: https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1080595 start with *Step 2: Download a new copy of the OS*

Answer (score 0):

Try booting your chrome book with [gparted live](https://gparted.org/livecd.php). You can get all the partition info and missing partition you mentioned there.

Be careful while restoring partitions, take the backup before you restore or create a partition.

Comment: Trying to get rid of the partition, would it still work?

Comment: If you just delete your missing partition, it should work. You can reclaim the space. As I mentioned, you have to be careful and handle correct partitions.